# How could I share "this" instance over my application in C++?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Say I have :

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::function< void(std::shared_ptr< Foo >) > callback);

    void shareMyFoo()
    {
        callback(std::make_shared< Foo >(this));
    }

    ....
};
```

When `shareMyFoo()` is invoked, someone will have a chance to copy the *shared pointer*. Unfortunately, as it will die --that is, its ref counter dropped to 0--, it will kill my Foo. I would like to prevent `Foo` from being suicided.

I thought of having a field `std::shared_ptr< Foo > sharedSelf_` in `Foo`, that I would initialize in the constructor, but that's cheap as well.

More generally, imagine I instantiate and store a pointer to an object in a *shared pointer*, (`auto foo = std::make_shared< Foo >()` for instance), and later the instance wants to pass itself as a shared pointer. How can I update the ref counter globally ?

*N.B.* : I want/need to preserve my signatures/my shared_ptr arguments over my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` (n3242 §20.7.2.4).

```
auto p = (new Foo) -> shared_from_this ();
```

Comment: `auto p = (new Foo) -> shared_from_this ();` What's that?

Comment: @spraff: Please explain it. How can that work? `shared_from_this` should only work on objects that are alrdy owned by  a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: No, if you want to create a `shared_ptr` from a `shared_ptr`, we have copy constructors. `shared_from_this` is the member function bestowed to `Foo` by inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this<Foo>`. It's a contrived example, but it's a simple, direct demonstration of a member function which creates a `shared_ptr` from `this`.

Answer (score 3):

Look up [enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html)

```
class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
    Foo(std::function< void(std::shared_ptr< Foo >) > callback);
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> create(std::function< void(std::shared_ptr< Foo >) > callback)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(std::move(callback)));
    }

    void shareMyFoo()
    {
        callback(shared_from_this());
    }
};
```